# Why are Binary Trees Important?

Tags: data-structures, tree

Why we do we study binary trees specifically? As in a general m-way search tree is not given as importance as binary trees in DataStructure textbooks.

Does the use of a binary tree exceed m-way trees?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Binary trees are the simplest form of multi-way trees so they're easier to study in that sense.

Multi-way trees have nodes that consist of `N` keys and `N+1` pointers, along the lines of:

```
               |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
   | k00 | k01 | k02 | k03 |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
  /      |     |     |      \
p00     p01   p02   p03     p04
```

To find out which pointer to follow in a search, you compare the key you're looking for against the keys in the node. That example above is an order-2 multi-way tree (I'm defining order `n` as having `2n` keys and `2n+1` pointers).

When you "degenerate" this structure to have the smallest node possible, you end up with one key and two pointers, your classical binary tree:

```
      |
   +-----+
   | k00 |
   +-----+
  /       \
p00       p01
```

When I went to university (and I'll freely admit that it was a while ago), we studied binary trees *first*, simply because the algorithms were elegant. Search was a simple compare node and select one of two sub-trees. Insertion and deletion were also relatively easy.

Then we went on to *balanced* binary trees, where search was exactly the same but insertion and deletion were a little more complicated, involving 'rotating' of sub-trees through the sub-tree root where necessary to keep it balanced.

This was then followed by non-balanced multi-way trees to get the concept of searching within a node once you've found the correct node then, finally, balanced multi-way trees which were basically the same as binary trees but with that same added complexity of a sequential search, as well as insertion or deletion within the node and combining and spitting of nodes themselves.

At each of those steps you simply added a little more complexity to the algorithms. I don't recall too many people having trouble with that progression so maybe all the textbooks you mention are just at the starter level.

I've never really found multi-way trees to be more useful than binary trees except in one very specific situation. That's when you're reading nodes of the tree from a slow medium like disk and you've optimized for sector/cluster/block sizes.

We developed a multi-way tree implementation under OS/2 (showing my age here) which screamed along, by ensuring the nodes were identical in size to the underlying disk blocks. Even though this could result in some wasted space, the speed improvements were worth it.

For in-memory stuff, binary trees have all the advantages of multi-ways with none of the extra complications (having to combine sequential search of a node with sub-tree selection).

Binary trees boil down to "Should we move left or right?", multi-ways are "Where's the key in this node so that we can choose the sub-tree?".

Answer (score 5):

Binary trees are a simple concept, they are easy to understand, easy to implement, and work well and fast -- I suppose this is enough for teaching and/or using them.

Comment: A B-Tree is a kind of m-way tree. I guess you meant binary tree, right?

Comment: @Thomas : ouch, I always though "B-tree" was a shortcut for "Binary-tree" ;; once again, I learnt something answering a question on SO ;; thanks !

Answer (score 1):

An advantage of binary trees over 'n-ary' trees is that traversing them often boils down to a simple yes/no decision problem, as in [binary space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).

Answer (score 1):

Because tree data structures are often used to organize ordered elements, e.g: a > b > c.  If your items that are inserted in the trees are ordered, all you need are two branches at each node to divide elements that are larger into the left sub-tree, and elements that are smaller into the right sub-tree.

This is why binary trees are so much more prevalent that m-ary trees.  It has nothing to do with the ease of making a yes/no decision versus a m-ary decision!

Comment: A better response... paul.. U have given an example. A>b>C.. but if you will try to derive a tree out of it.. how you gonna do this step by step. Following is the Algo:
A introduced. Add as it is.
B introduced. B<A.. move to left of A. (True / False decision)
C introduced. c<b.. move to left of B. (True / False decision)
On that basis I said its combination of yes/no.. and true false.. only Binary tree can do this for you. BST is much more meaningful though. Anyway, thanks for your comments

Comment: U can use B+tree to preserve the order, so we can say.. Binary is not even used for orders :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the all answers above, a tree of any arity can be represented by a binary tree (where left link goes to the first child of the node, and the right link goes to the next "brother").

Answer (score -1):

I am not going to be too much techi here.. because the question is why Binary Tree is give so much importance in DataStructure. Binary Tree ,, means tree based on T/F, Yes/No etc. Mean to say the combination of Duo. Practically we face the situation where we need to decide yes or no.. True or False. Binary tree represents such a situation. The softwares we work on,, are the solutions which gonna use the data-structures internally used to solve the real life scenarios.. That's why binary tree coming into picture and is commonly used and even important too. Rest of the trees are further refinements or the added complexities to match them with the typical situations. For starting Binary tree is always important.

Comment: Indeed, but I think that it's a language barrier in this case.

Answer (score -2):

For example, binary trees are used for Heap sorting (Binary Heap). This is way for very fast sorting data so that the biggest (or lowest) item always is at the front. This is used for example in AI (A* algorithm).